# How to make a random + or - value

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm trying to add or subtract from 1 to 5 numbers.

So far I have:

```
var number:int = Math.random() * 5;
```

Now I want to make it random as either positive or negative.

Can I use the following:

```
// use math random to pick 1 or 0 and if 0 then negative
number = Math.random() * 1 ? number : number * -1;
```

but I don't like it. In my experience with Math random, the number will always be 0???. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know if I should create another question but is there some Math function that is just pick a number from 1 - 3? Something like `Math.pickANumberFrom(1, 3);` or `Math.pickAny(0, 1, 2);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var plusOrMinusVal = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(Math.random()) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

- `Math.random()` - random from 0 to 1, *0.54398938*
- `Math.round()` - round number to rational value, *0.54398938 is now 1*
- `x > 0 ? 1 : -1` - check if x is bigger than 0, assign 1, else -1, *1 is bigger than 0 - assign 1*

```js
function random(){
  document.querySelector('#number').innerHTML =  Math.round(Math.random()) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

```html
<h3>You randomed: <span id="number">x</span></h3>
<button onclick="random()">Try again</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. You beat the system dude, http://imgur.com/9VSEieN StackOverflow can't believe you could answer so fast!

Comment: What about just a simple `[1, -1][+(Math.random() > 0.5)]`  or use a ternary operator? Rounding it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 well, it's the case of preference, i personally don't like hardcoding

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly But you hardcoded three numbers in your code as well. `Math.round(Math.random()) > 0` is not easily understandable.

Comment: I would say `[1, -1][+(Math.random() > .5]` is too much mental effort for such a little thing. For me the clearest is `Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) - 5;
```

`floor` will give normal distribution of values while `round` will not for min and max values. But then you should remember add 1 to argument. Also, `Math.random()` never returns 1, it means in this case we never get 11 from `Math.floor`. Maximum possible value is 10.